# Which methodology Heroku uses to spin dyno worker?

Tags: heroku, lxc

I have been using heroku for previous 4-5 years, and most recently got to work on Infra as code and i was wondering which technology/methodology Heroku uses for sniping dynos or workers, I have tried searching online whether its LXC or something else but was not able to find any answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses LXC:

*Each application on the Heroku platform runs within its own isolated environment and cannot interact with other applications or areas of the system. This restrictive operating environment is designed to prevent security and stability issues.  **These self-contained environments isolate processes, memory, and the file system using LXC** while host-based firewalls restrict applications from establishing local network connections.*

Source: https://www.heroku.com/policy/security